# How to remove Python 2 in 16.04?

Tags: package-management, python, uninstall, 16.04

Ubuntu has [dropped Python 2](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#Python_3) in 16.04. It is still installed after an upgrade, though (it was not part of the "obsolete packages").

Is there a clean way to remove Python 2 **and all its dependencies** in a clean way (to completely get rid of it)?

Is an `apt purge` the way to go?

```
root@ubuntu ~# apt purge python2.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libnss-ldap
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  auth-client-config* ldap-auth-client* ldap-auth-config* libpam-ldap* libsmbclient* ndiff* python* python-bs4* python-chardet* python-crypto* python-dnspython*
  python-html5lib* python-ldb* python-lxml* python-ntdb* python-pkg-resources* python-samba* python-setuptools* python-six* python-talloc* python-tdb* python2.7* samba*
  samba-common-bin* samba-dsdb-modules* samba-libs* samba-vfs-modules* smbclient* winbind*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 29 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 58.4 MB disk space will be freed.
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "clean way"? Python2 is only installed if some of the packages need it. Removing it might break the system.

Comment: @mikewhatever: I did an upgrade from 15.10 where Python 2 was needed by the system. Since 16.04 does not ship it at all it means it is not needed anymore. So removing Python 2 should not break the system - which is what I fear the most. As for extra software - it does not matter if they break (I will remove them as well in that case)

Comment: Well, good luck then. :~)

Comment: However, *many* apps still need it. Maybe the update installed something requiring `python2`? I'd say don't remove it.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju: wouldn't `apt purge` show me the dependencies? - and allow me to make up my mind (in my case `samba` would be a problematic package to remove for instance)

Comment: @WoJ I mean't that you don't need it *yet*. However, so many apps depend on it that it is going to be installed sooner or later.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**As there are still a lot of packages that depend on Python2 (like Samba and VirtualBox) you should have a close look at the packages that apt wants to remove before you let it proceed.**

Use

```
sudo apt purge python2.7-minimal
```

to completely remove Python2 and everything that depends on it.

Comment: I just did it, and many things got uninstalled. So far the only I'm missing is "duplicity", so my deja-dup backup copies are now broken because deja-dup relies on duplicity. It seems there's still not a duplicity version that supports python 3, and they keep doing changes with python 2.7, so it's unlikely it's going to be one anywhere in the near future. It's somehow a shame because deja-dup is the default backup system in Ubuntu.

Comment: JFTR, the pulseaudio-equalizer also seem to depend on Python2 still...

Comment: Calibre ebook application also depends on python 2.7

Comment: The Gimp also depends on python 2.7

Comment: You should never do this! I did it and now my system is all fucked up!

Comment: I'm here because I wanted to run an app with Python 3.6+.

Comment: I read the comment too late....

Comment: The correct package name is `libpython2-minimal`, not `python2-minimal`.